# Facebook SDK in internal application, share video with FB.ui

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk, share

I have a proble when i try to share any video with facebook SDK JavaScript in internal application. In the past used (method: 'feed') but in new API is deprecated. I try to do the same with the new API but i get this error: {error_code: 2, error_message: "This feature is not available: There was an error processing this request. Please try again later."}

my old code is:

```
FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        name: username,
        picture: picture,
        description: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + video,
        link: facebookShareUrl
    });
```

but this method is deprecated with the new API.

my new code is:

```
FB.ui({
        method: 'share_open_graph',
        action_type: 'video.watches',
        action_properties: JSON.stringify({
            video: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + video
        })
    }, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

Comment: Use the share dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

Comment: I need customize some details from my applications, image or video, title, description..

Comment: Yes? You specify og-tags on the url you share.

Comment: is not a url, is a layout of tha same page, you can write an example?

Comment: You want to share a url I assume? And the documentation I linked to shows exactly how to do it

Comment: I have the project in locahost :\